# NetSuite Advanced PDF / HTML error: "Parse exception during template merging. Unexpected end of file reached."

Tags: html, templates, pdf, freemarker, netsuite

I have created a complex Advanced PDF / HTML Template using freemarker. When I make no changes and attempt to save the template, the template saves with no errors. When I add a new field to the template through the UI or even simple HTML "Test" and then try to save, I get the following error:

> "Parse exception during template merging.
>   com.netledger.templates.TemplateServiceException: Parse exception
>   during template merging. freemarker.core.ParseException: Unexpected
>   end of file reached."

If I proceed and save anyway, the printed PDF gives the same error and displays:
 `"The template stored was invalid"`. What does this error mean and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

It means that you have some FreeMarker construct in the template that weren't closed. Like, and `${` without the matching `}`, or an `<#if ...>` without the matching `</#if>`.

BTW, usually the error message also tells what wasn't closed. Perhaps you are using an old FreeMarker version where error message quality was lower. You may try to copy-paste the template into http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/ to see what a more recent version says.